# how can i resize and partition thepart in hard disk where the system setup?

Tags: partitioning, 14.10, gparted, system, resize

i erased my hard disk by wrong during setup ubuntu 14.04 and it put all my hard disk in  dev/sda1 (463.88 GB)( and my system(ubuntu) also setup in dev/sda1) and the other space in swap 
i tried to use GParted but it didn't want to resize or partition what should i to to partition my hard disk ?

Comment: And... Now you want to recover lost data? Or simply re-partition your disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To repartition your disk, the partitions you want to change (every operation except enlarging) have to be unmounted. This means that the running OS is not accessing them. You can recognize a mounted partition by the key symbol next to its name in gParted and you will see that both of your partitions (mount points / and swap) are mounted.

So it is impossible when you boot from your installed Ubuntu version, you have to boot from a live media. Insert the Ubuntu installation DVD/USB stick, select "Try Ubuntu" and run gParted from within this live session. You will see that the partitions on the hard disk are now unmounted (no key symbols) and you can modify them.

Anyway: Partitioning always might lead to data loss. **So backup your important data before performing this.** Especially operations like shrinking/moving partitions may damage the data, while moving the left border of a bootable partition might lead to problems with GRUB and no booting anymore. (This can be solved by running `boot-repair` or `update-grub` from within the live session after mounting the hdd partitions)

Comment: ty very much for the perfect answer and your cooperation :)